# Angular 2+ , Router navigates to destinated route but wont load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, web

I am trying to navigate to diffrent component in the same module using [routerLink] inside template
, but somehow the destinated component wont load therefore i stay at the same component.

code:

```
  `file : site.module.ts 
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SiteRoutingModule,
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SiteModule { }`

file: site-routing-module.ts

    import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./pages/home/home.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./pages/login/login.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '**', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class SiteRoutingModule {

}

file: home.component.html 
    <button class="have-ins-btn"[routerLink]="['/login']" [queryParams]="{ins_exists: false}"
```

Comment: forgot to mention , im using <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the main module app.component.html

Comment: Hi @yarin, you mean homepage is only loading when you navigate to login

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing route order like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

Comment: Well seems like it solved the issue, could you please explain why is that?

Comment: ** pattern will match all routes. So if it is  login then it will trigger ** pattern first which will obviously load homecomponent. By updating the route order like login first and ** as last, then first occurance will definitely trigger exact match component and return. One more option available in Routes is pathMatch: full